# JasmineJS: Test angular factory with dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I have a factory defined like this:

```
angular.module("myServices")
    .factory("$service1", ["$rootScope", "$service2", function($rootScope, $service2){...})];
```

Now, I want to test it, but just injecting $service1 is not working because i get an 'unknown provider' error. So I tried something like that. But I still can't make it work. Why?

```
beforeEach(function() {
        module("myServices");

        inject(function ($injector) {
            dependencies["$service2"] = $injector.get("$service2");
        });

        module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value("$service1", dependencies["$service2"]);
        });

        inject(function($injector) {
            factory = $injector.get("$service1");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's working in my tests, using [underscores](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject#resolving-references-underscore-wrapping-):

```
describe('Service: $service1', function () {

    var $service2, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$service2_, $rootScope) {
        $service2 = _$service2_;
        scope = $rootScope;
    }));

    //tests
});
```

If that still doesn't work, then maybe you're not loading the relevant files (such as service2.js) in your tests.